# What does "Lizard in a ruin" mean in this Paragraph?

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning, semantics, idiom-meaning, paragraphs

Paragraph ([Taken from here](http://www.lrb.co.uk/v38/n10/bee-wilson/like-cold-oysters)):

> *You can watch Piaf performing ‘La Foule’ on YouTube, in a recording of a concert in the Netherlands in December 1962. It is completely
>   mesmerising. A journalist who saw her live in 1939 described her as
>   ‘part wounded animal, part passionate woman’. There is no hint that
>   the song had been written more than two decades earlier, in another
>   language, for other singers. Piaf delivers it as piercing
>   confessional, and she its only narrator. As always, she wears a black
>   dress, and while the introduction plays, she looks down and clicks her
>   fingers. Then she suddenly flicks her head up and looks accusingly at
>   the crowd, her white hands glued to the side of her body **(Cocteau
>   said she had hands like ‘a lizard in a ruin’).** She looks much older
>   and frailer than 47, but however disoriented she is pretending to be,
>   she hardly sways at all and her gestures are deliberate. She sings
>   with brutal force, wringing maximum vibrations from her rolling ‘Rs’
>   (‘entrrrrraînés parrrrr la foule’ – ‘carried along by the rushing
>   crowd’). She may be accusing the crowd with her words, but with her
>   body and voice, she is seducing them. When her last word is done, she
>   continues the story with gestures, dancing now, as if doing a mad
>   farandole with the crowd, her eyes half-closed and her feet tapping.
>   The applause roars to a crescendo and the film cuts for a moment to
>   rows of bourgeois Dutch men and women in smart evening dress palpably
>   thrilled to be Piaf’s crowd for a night.*

This paragraph is describing gestures of a woman (Edith piaf) while singing "LaFoule".

1. In the bold part, I think the woman's body is
   compared with ruin.
2. From the paragraph, it seems author trying to potray a mesmerising image of the opera singer, then why **lizard**
   and **ruin** are doing here? Does any positive connotation
   associated with them? (looks to me like an antique idiom :P)
3. Is the author saying her hands looked more
   elegant ( or disgraceful) than her body or vice versa?

> NOTE : In my country, comparing someone/something with the lizard is
>   not good at all. we associate it with impurity.

Comment: Interpretation of literature is [off-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to interpretation of literature.

Comment: It's a treat to have a question that mentions Piaf and Cocteau.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lizard comparison implies that she held her hands motionless or very still. Cocteau's comparison is added as a parenthetic remark to corroborate the statement that her hands were "glued to the side of her body".

You can see from this [n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as%20*%20as%20a%20lizard&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cas%20%2A%20as%20a%20lizard%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bas%20quick%20as%20a%20lizard%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bas%20green%20as%20a%20lizard%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bas%20cold%20as%20a%20lizard%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bas%20close%20as%20a%20lizard%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bas%20beautiful%20as%20a%20lizard%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bas%20easily%20as%20a%20lizard%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bas%20still%20as%20a%20lizard%3B%2Cc0) that "still" is high on the list of qualities associated with lizards.